# Flutter - Count List with bool

Tags: flutter

In Flutter I've created a List with booleans.

```
List<bool> name = [false, false, false]
```

The Values change to true on a togglebutton click.

How is it possible to count the values on reloading the page?

My attempt was inside the initState to count the List if it contains true.

```
value = name.contains(true).length
```

But it always says length isn't defined for the class 'bool'.

How can I count it on reload of the page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use `where` instead of `contains`

```dart
value = name.where((item) => item == false).length
```

> bool Iterable.contains(Object element) Returns true if the collection
>   contains an element equal to [element].
>
> This operation will check each element in order for being equal to
>   [element], unless it has a more efficient way to find an element equal
>   to [element].
>
> The equality used to determine whether [element] is equal to an
>   element of the iterable defaults to the [Object.==] of the element.
>
> Some types of iterable may have a different equality used for its
>   elements. For example, a [Set] may have a custom equality (see
>   [Set.identity]) that its contains uses. Likewise the Iterable returned
>   by a [Map.keys] call should use the same equality that the Map uses
>   for keys.
>
> - from Dart Docs

TLDR: `contains` returns bool indicating whether the list "contains" an item or not.

Comment: to count TRUE values as it in question need to use `name.where((item) => item).length` but not `item == false`

Comment: T H A N K  Y O U

Answer (score 1):

Old way but easy to understand... **FOR**:

> ```
> int countBoolList(List<bool> boolList) {
>   int count = 0;
>   for (int i = 0; i < boolList.length; i++) {
>     if (boolList.elementAt(i) == true) {
>       count++;
>     }
>   }
>   return count;
> }
>
> void main() {
>   List<bool> name = [false, false, true, false];
>   print(countBoolList(name)); //output: 1
> }
> ```