# How do I calculate a percentage based on a List of booleans?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of booleans here:

```dart
List<bool> list = [false, false, false, false];
```

Using that as an example, if I were to find the percentage of values that are `true`, it would be `0%`.

Using another example:

```dart
List<bool> list = [true, true, false, false];
```

The percentage of values that are `true` would be `50%`.

I was able to find something similar to what I need here: [Flutter - Count List with bool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60409292/4126418) which works.

However, the calculations to percentages are a little lost on me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically just the number of `true` elements divided by the total number of elements.

```dart
void main() {
  List<bool> list = [true, true, false, false];
  double percent = list.where((v) => v).length / list.length;
  String percentString = '${(percent * 100).round()}%';
  print(percent);
  print(percentString);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably do something like :

```
  int trueValues = list.fold(0, (acc, val) => val ? ++acc : acc);
  double truePercent = trueValues / list.length;
```

count the number of 'true' value and divide it by the list size (total number of values)